Issues with calling Unmanaged C++ method in ASP.Net Web API project
I have an unmanaged C++ DLL which I am trying to use in my ASP.Net Core Web API project. I have created a wrapper in .Net and I've provided the GUIDs of my Interface and Class (GUIDs from regedit) to create the object. I've used TlbImp.exe to create an Interop DLL which I'm referencing in .Net and I have registered both the original and Interop DLL as well using regsvr32 and regasm.
I am not getting any errors during object creation or during function call, but the return value is incorrect rather it looks like it's always returning a default value of 1 which is incorrect based on the logic of my method.
C++ code:
//Header File:

//CxIDTrans
class ATL_NO_VTABLE __declspec(dllexport) CxIDTrans : 
   public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
   public CComCoClass<CxIDTrans, &CLSID_xIDTrans>,
   public ISupportErrorInfo,
   public IxIDTrans,
   public IxIDTransVC
{
public:
   DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_XIDTRANS)

   DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

   BEGIN_COM_MAP(CxIDTrans)
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IxIDTrans)
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IxIDTransVC)
   END_COM_MAP()
   
   CxIDTrans();
  ~CxIDTrans();
  
  //----------------
   // IxIDTrans
   //----------------
  
  STDMETHOD(GetID)(long *outID);
};


//CPP File
STDMETHODIMP CxIDTrans::GetID(long *outID)
{
    //Some logic
}

Wrapper Code:
namespace someNamespace
{
    public class ComInterop
    {
        [ComImport, Guid("Interface GUID"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IxIDTrans
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int GetID(out long outID);
        }

        public class IDTransWrapper
        {
            private readonly IxIDTrans _IDTrans;

            public IDTransWrapper()
            {
                Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("Class GUID"));
                _IDTrans = (IxIDTrans)Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
            }

            public long GetID()
            {
                int hr;
                long outID = 0;

                var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    hr = _IDTrans.GetID(out outID);
                    if (hr != 0)
                    {
                        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
                    }
                });
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
                
                return outID;
            }
        }
    }
}

I've added __declspec(dllexport) to the C++ code and thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA), thread.Start() and thread.Join() to .Net based on a couple of suggestions.
PS: The return value of outID is set to 0 which after the function call is always 1, which is not the correct value based on my logic. Also the return value of hr is 0 (S_OK). I've added logs in my GetID() method but those logs are never being created and also tried running the SQL Profiler as there are couple of DB calls within this method but I'm not surprised that profiler doesn't display anything when this method is called. Also I'm not 100% sure if the .Net Framework version could cause an issue as this C++ is built on an older platform and also it's a 32-bit DLL. I will not be able to do much changes in C++ project as this DLL is being used by other functionalities as well.
Any help would be appreciated and do let me know if any further data is required.
